# Why does the origin disappear in Shading tab?

Tags: interface, origin

I have notice that the little dot origin point is not visible in the shading tab editor, why does it disappear? When I go back to modelling or editing it reappears.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every workspace has its own settings. The *Shading* tab has it disabled by default for reasons where you have to ask the designers or developers. Enable *Origins* under *Viewport Overlays*

[image]